# MS CRM Web API blocked by CORS policy

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am facing API blocked by CORS policy error when I am trying to access data from my custom webAPI.

Below is the code I am using to make webAPI call.

```
var orgurl = "<web api url>";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", encodeURI(orgurl), false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'false');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        console.log("this.status: " + this.status);
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log("this.response: " + this.response);
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.name = result[i].NAME;
                    console.log("obj: " + obj);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert(this.statusText);
    }
};

req.send();
```

below is error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin
>   'https://.dynamics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Above code is working fine if i am using chrome after disable-web-security.
    using command  `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

I have added CROS Origin allow settings in Web API C# config and controller files as well, still I am unable to get response from my Web API.

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot directly call webapi from another service.
Rather you need to create an application in azure give permission to dynamics online and for that application ignore CORAS.
You will need non interactive user to use this functionality.
Here is the link for reference.

https://medium.com/capgemini-dynamics-365-team/dynamics-365-application-users-no-additional-license-required-and-no-limit-on-quantity-4bdc49f8ce2d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.inogic.com/blog/2018/07/is-it-possible-to-createupdate-application-user-in-dynamics-365-programmatically/amp/